# Run python script after pushing ladda button

Tags: php, python

I've made a few python scripts that I want to execute when I push a ladda button.
https://lab.hakim.se/ladda/

First I've created a php file to run the python script

```
<?php

$command = escapeshellcmd('/www/html/enable_s1.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
header( "refresh:3;url=index.php" );
?>
```

This works without any problems

Next I've created a page to test the ladda button. This also works. 
But now I want to link an action to the button. I want to run a python script after a button is pressed.

When I also include the php code to execute python, it will run everytime the page loads. 
How can I stop this behavior?
Is PHP for executing the python script the best option?

Comment: > How can I stop this behavior?
Put the button in a form and have php check for form submission.
> Is PHP for executing the python script the best option?
Maybe, depends on the use-case

Comment: First of all, why you need to execute a python script over PHP Code?

Comment: @castis, I want to stay on the same page. Is that possible with a form? It was the first thing that came in my mind. And I know it works. Now I need to figure out how to postpone the execution.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this code useful for you :

`index.html` file :

```
<form action="test.php">
    <button type="submit" class="ladda-button" data-color="green" data-style="expand-left"><span class="ladda-label">Submit</span><span class="ladda-spinner"></span></button>
</form>
```

`test.php` file :

```
<?php
exec('python3.6 enable_s1.py', $output);
?>
```

`enable_s1.py` file :

```
print(' hi everybody')
# do somthing
```